# How can deploying laravel app on shared host?

Tags: laravel, shared-hosting

I have installed a laravel app on host but faced with this error below. I've installed 2 or 3 another laravel app on shared host without any problem , I know the way but in this case i can't figure it out what is problem, I'm new in laravel.

This is error :

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Class 'Orangehill\Iseed\IseedServiceProvider' not found
```

Comment: whats your orangehill/iseed version and laravel version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, It is better to install Laravel applications on `Subdomain` and `Domain`. After moving the application to `subdomain` every things worked perfectly.
Also This link is a good guide for [installing laravel on Subdirectory](https://medium.com/@lucabecchetti/configure-laravel-to-work-in-a-subdirectory-and-with-artisan-serve-at-the-same-time-654ba0c1fd0b)

Answer (score 0):

For Hosting Laravel 7 app you need to follow these requirements on the server

```
PHP >= 7.2.5

BCMath PHP Extension

Ctype PHP Extension

Fileinfo PHP extension

JSON PHP Extension

Mbstring PHP Extension

OpenSSL PHP Extension

PDO PHP Extension

Tokenizer PHP Extension

XML PHP Extension
```

For more info you can read a complete document of Laravel => [Laravel-server-needs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x#server-requirements)

Comment: Exactly we need to follow this steps for production.